# Creating local coordinate system in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I am trying to create my own coordinate system in QGIS. My local system is defined as: base is Sweref 99 20 15 and then Helmert transformation with these parameters:

```
// Local transformation
Description: 
(3D) 2D Helmert + sloping plane
X0: -1808725.6468
Y0: 7224756.0786
Z0: 0.0000
R11: 0.2204
R12: 0.9754
R13: 0.0000
R21: -0.9754
R22: 0.2204
R23: -0.0000
R31: -0.0000
R32: 0.0000
R33: 1.0000
RotX (deg): 0.000000000
RotY (deg): 0.000000000
RotZ (deg): -77.269994901
Scale: 1.000030133
```

I have tried this proj but its not right, I have troubles with units, proj of sweref I have taken from QGIS database.

```
+proj=pipeline
+step 
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=20.25 +k=1 +x_0=150000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs

+step 
+proj=helmert +convention=coordinate_frame
+x=-1808725.647 +y=7224756.079 +z=0 +rx=0.0
+ry=0.0 +rz=-85.85554989 +s=1.00003013
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: I suspect you would need to look up wkt projection and use that.  From my understanding there are limitations with what can be expressed in proj strings.

Comment: This is way outside my area of confidence, so I may be completely off the mark, but why is RotZ given as about -77° (which seems consistent with the R01-R31 values, assuming they form a matrix), but `+rz` is -85° ?

Comment: its because -85 is gon not degree..

Comment: But the [docs](https://proj.org/en/latest/operations/transformations/helmert.html) seem to say it’s supposed to be arc seconds?